# How do you convert a Django model with ManytoMany field to an elasticsearch_dsl DocType class?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm using elasticsearch_dsl to help with interfacing with elasticsearch and this is the model I currently have and I'm trying to recreate as a DocType:

```
class HouseIndex(DocType):
    house_type = String()
    #people
    sold = Boolean()
    built_datetime = Date()
    #alerts
    # associated_locations
    hash = String()


class House(models.Model):
    house_type = models.ForeignKey(HouseType, db_index=True,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    people = models.ManyToManyField(to='Person', db_index=True,
                                      through='PersonToHouseMap')
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    built_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    alerts = models.ManyToManyField(Alert)
    associated_locations = models.ManyToManyField(to='Location')
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, null=True)
    objects = HouseManager()
```

But I'm not sure what to do when it's a ManyToMany field. Such as with people, alerts, and associated locations.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you wish to query for, but I'd probably use a `Nested` field containing a list of the `Location` objects. You can see something similar in my example repo here - https://github.com/HonzaKral/es-django-example/blob/master/qa/models.py#L48

Comment: is the method `to_search` effectively the serializer?

Comment: Yes, it is - it take a model instance and produces an instance of `DocType`. With changes to `Nested` in `6.0` even the `Comment.to_search` would produce an instance of an `InnerDoc` subclass and not just dictionary.